# I am not able to drag the text using matrix gesture dector package, it only drags in a small area and vanishes

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used matrix gesture detector package to drag the text and images, however it seems only the image can be drag successfully while the text drags in a small area such that it vanishes.

```
class CustomOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const CustomOverlay({required this.child,Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      onMatrixUpdate: (matrix, translationDeltaMatrix, scaleDeltaMatrix, rotationDeltaMatrix) {
        notifier.value=matrix;
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: notifier,
        builder: (context, childWidget) {
          return Transform(
              transform: notifier.value,
              child: FittedBox(
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: child,
              )
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This one is the custom widget using matrix gesture detector

```
Text( 
 'Sample',
 style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors.white,
  ),                            
),
```

This one is a text widget which will be used in stack

```
SizedBox(
                  height: size.height*0.5,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      ColorFiltered(
                        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(hoodieColor, BlendMode.modulate),
                        child: Image.asset(apparelDesign[1]['image'],fit: BoxFit.cover,height: size.height*0.5,width: size.width,)
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: size.height*0.2,
                        left: size.width*0.35,
                        child: Container(
                          height: size.height*0.225,
                          width: size.width*0.3,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              width: 1,
                            )
                          ),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              for(int i=0;i<customWidgets.length;i++)
                                customWidgets[i],
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]
                  ),
                )
```

customWidget is list of widgets which includes both the text and an image which can be dragged around the container which is restricted so the widgets can only be drag and placed inside the container only

I wanted the text able to move(drag) freely inside the container and it should be fit properly inside the container

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.
I have used constrained box in place of the fitted box

```html
class CustomOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double? height;
  final double? width;
  const CustomOverlay({ this.height,this.width,required this.child,Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ValueNotifier<Matrix4> notifier = ValueNotifier(Matrix4.identity());
    return MatrixGestureDetector(
      shouldScale: true,
      shouldRotate: false,
      onMatrixUpdate: (matrix, translationDeltaMatrix, scaleDeltaMatrix, rotationDeltaMatrix) {
        notifier.value=matrix;
      },
      child: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: notifier,
        builder: (context, childWidget) {
          return Transform(
              transform: notifier.value,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: height,width: width),
                child: child,
              )
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```